# while loop not working correctly (Python)

Tags: python

I have come across a problem with this code and I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it.

This code is for a game based on a board and this code creates two lists of 20 coordinates under each of the variables `treasure_coords` and `bandit_coords`. These lists of coordinates can not have the coordinate `(0, 11)` in them and none of the co-ordinates can be in both lists.

I thought I had stopped this happening by adding `bandit_coords in treasure_coords` to my while loop but when the code runs it still creates some of the same coordinates in both lists, and this is the problem. Please reply with any useful feedback.

```
import random
board = []
for x in range(12):
    board.append(["[ ]"]*12)
coord_creater = [(x, y) for x in range(len(board[0])) for y in range(len(board))]
treasure_coords = random.sample(coord_creater, 20)
bandit_coords = random.sample(coord_creater, 20)
while (0,11) in treasure_coords or (0,11) in bandit_coords or bandit_coords in treasure_coords:
    treasure_coords = random.sample(coord_creater, 20)
    bandit_coords = random.sample(coord_creater, 20)
print (treasure_coords)
print (bandit_coords)
```

Comment: Do you have to use a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `in` to check if any element of a list is inside another. `in` checks if an individual element is inside a list.

In this case, `any` is your friend. This will check if any of the elements in a list is True. Combining this with generators will do the trick.

```
bandit_coords in treasure_coords
```

Needs to be replaced by:

```
any([coord in treasure_coords for coord in bandit_coords ])
```

This will create a list with a Boolean checking if every single coordinate in bandit_coords is in treasure_coords and then check if any of them is `True`

Comment: @jDo `(0,11) in treasure_coords` is a correct usage of `in`. `bandit_coords in treasure_coords` is not, since both are `list` of `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not sure that a while loop is the best way to go, but here are two possible implementations:

```
import random
board = []
for x in range(12):
    board.append(["[ ]"]*12)
possible_cords = [(x,y) for x in range(len(board[0])) for y in range(len(board))]

# we don't want any item at (0,11)
invalid_cord = possible_cords.pop(11)
treasure_cords = list()
bandit_cords = list()
```

Option 1:

```
for x in range(20):
    treasure_at = random.choice(possible_cords)
    possible_cords.pop(possible_cords.index(treasure_at))
    bandit_at = random.choice(possible_cords)
    possible_cords.pop(possible_cords.index(bandit_at))
    treasure_cords.append(treasure_at)
    bandit_cords.append(bandit_at)
print zip(treasure_cords, bandit_cords)
```

Option 2:

```
# or if you must use a while loop
count = 0
while count < 20:
    treasure_at = random.choice(possible_cords)
    possible_cords.pop(possible_cords.index(treasure_at))
    bandit_at = random.choice(possible_cords)
    possible_cords.pop(possible_cords.index(bandit_at))
    treasure_cords.append(treasure_at)
    bandit_cords.append(bandit_at)
    count += 1
print zip(treasure_cords, bandit_cords)
```

Comment: Ok, what would I do if I wanted, say 10 bandits and 20 treasure?

Comment: Use two different loops. One for the bandits and one for the treasures. Since you are pop positions off the list, it doesn't matter.